# Why does S06E08 feature so many guest stars?

Tags: production, casting, its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia

The [*It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472954/) episode "The Gang Gets a New Member" (S06E08) features three significantly famous actors/comedians in guest roles, that being *Jason Sudeikis* as former group member, *Dave Foley* as high school principal, and *Rene Auberjonois* as *Sweet Dee*'s former acting teacher.

For a show that rarely features many non-regulars (if any) at all, this high frequency of familiar faces struck me as pretty remarkable. **Is there any specific reason that this particular episode freatured that many famous guest stars** or was this just a coincidence/the usual business?